# Using fluent mapping on descendant types with glass mapper

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a type that I'm mapping (`FooterFolder`) which has a property of `SocialMedia` which I want to map using its own fluent configuration.

Here's the configuration of the Footer

```
loader.Add<FooterFolder>()
        .TemplateId("3E1C2A35-C62C-4FCE-B576-787F23E7728D")
        .AutoMap()
        .Fields(config =>
        {
            config.Field(x => x.LogoLink)
               .FieldName("Logo Link");
        })
        .Query(x => x.SocialLinks).IsRelative().InferType().Query("./Social Links/*");
```

And the SocialMedia

```
loader.Add<SocialMedia>()
        .TemplateId("1A1D6464-CB5A-433F-B7A9-9D10FA8E4BFE")
        .AutoMap()
        .Field(x => x.LinkLink).FieldName("Link");
```

If I change the name of the field on SocialMedia to just Link, it works (presumably using auto-mapping) but I'd like to have control over the mapping in case the name doesn't exactly match. Is there a way I can do this?

Here's my `FooterFolder` defenition:

```
public class FooterFolder : FolderBase
{
    public virtual string Copyright { get; set; }

    public virtual Image Logo { get; set; }

    public virtual Link LogoLink { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SocialMedia> SocialLinks { get; set; }
}
```

And `SocialMedia`:

```
public class SocialMedia : ContentBase
{
    public virtual Image Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual Link LinkLink { get; set; }

    public virtual string Shorthand { get; set; }
}
```

(I'm naming the property `LinkLink` just to test the mapping. Normally they'd only be different for things like `LogoLink` where there's a space in the Sitecore definition)

In sitecore, the `Social Media` has a `General Link` named `Link`. If I change the name of the property on `SocialMedia` to `Link` it works just fine, through auto-mapping, presumably.

Comment: To downvoter: Can I get an explanation as to why?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question doesn't the FieldName method allow you to specify the field name in Sitecore that the property maps to a la this link http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/HowTo/4-MappingAField. Or do you need a way to control the auto mapping process? I didn't down vote btw

Comment: Correct, FieldName does allow me to specify the field name, which I'm attempting to do on `SocialMedia.` The issue is that when the SocialLinks are loaded through the FooterFolder, they don't seem to run through that `FieldName` call.

Comment: Can you post up the definition of `SocialMedia` object and details of the template from Sitecore. Is `x => x.LinkLink` actually correct, that's the name of your property?

Comment: @jammykam: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up switching to using the `SitecoreGlassMap` version of configuration, rather than the `IConfigurationLoader` version, and it worked fine.